# How to select Mongo database dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I am building a saas application in angular, Mongo and PHP, where every user has its own database. 
The problem is that I have no idea how to select a database dynamically in PHP. I have tried this

```
function getStagingDbConn($m)
{
    $m = new MongoClient();
    return $m->selectDatabase( "demo_db" );
}
```

but it is not working.
i am using mongo 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$m = new MongoClient(); // connexion
$db = $m->selectDB("exemple");

?>
```

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php